# How to make a Widget change color briefly like a button

Tags: flutter, dart

So, Buttons behave in a way that will make the user know that he/she clicked the button[The button changes its foreground color briefly when clicked.]

Now my questions is how do i do it on a container in the way that when user clicks the widget, it becomes responsive[foreground darkens], and when user lifts finger from the widget[becomes normal]?

my Code for the Widget is below:

```
     Container(
                height: 60,
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  elevation: 1,
                  shadowColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            'Click Me',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.right_chevron,
                            color: color_primary,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an **InkWell** with a non-null **onTap** parameter around your **Padding** widget.

```
Container(
          height: 60,
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            elevation: 1,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
            child: InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              onTap: () {
                // do something on tap
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Click Me',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.right_chevron,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Also please take a look at a way you can achieve the same result without using a **Stack** (since it might be an overhead for this situation).

Comment: oh, i will be adding more stuffs under this Container thats why i used Stack. 
But will use something else when tht time comes

Comment: Also, This worked how i want it to work! Thank you for the InkWell.

Comment: Stack might be a better option to use if you want to overlay widgets. For anything else - Rows + Columns should do the work easily.